# highchart-ng update color on bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I want to change color on a bar dynamically in a column chart  using highchart-ng.
I see that the $watch function in highchart-ng is triggered each time the $interval is changing the color, but no update of the color is made eventhough the chart.redraw() is called each time.

However, if I at the same time add a new bar dynamically(see outcommented code in jsfiddle) the bar changes color.

jsfiddle.net/rick822/k7pbwch4/

Comment: You need to add the code that you want assistance with to your question.

Comment: This is bug in the 4.1.9 version of Highcharts, already fixed on the 4.1.10 prerelease, see github version: http://jsfiddle.net/k7pbwch4/8/